# Generalizing Keyboard Input

Tags: c++, linux, windows, keyboard

I'm currently writing on an engine for game development and I'm having a hard time in figuring out how to best generalize keyboard input.

I want to do something like:

```
void onKeyDown(int key)
{
  // Set key down state to true.
}
void onKeyUp(int key)
{
  // Set key down state to false.
}
void update()
{
  if (/* is key down */)
  {
    // Do something.
  }
}
```

Now I need to know in which data structure I have to save my key states. At first I thought a `bool[256]` array would be sufficient but what about the control characters?

Then I thought about using a map like `map< int, bool>`. Would this work for the different languages? I would want to check the key state with `key_states['a']` or with defined constants for unprintable characters like `key_states[Key::Enter]`. What if someone from asia would input some asian character? Would that work too?

On my linux machine there are 3 different 'representations' of a key. First there is a key code which seems to be impractical for what I'm trying to do. The next are representations are keysym and a string representation. Because I also need to know when a non-printable key is pressed (like e.g. the enter key) the string representation is not usable either I guess.

So that leaves me with the keysym. This is a little test output I generated on my linux (I clicked 'a', 'Shift-a', 'Ctrl-a' and 'Alt-a':

```
DOWN: KeyCode: 38 '&', KeySym: 97 'a', String: 'a'
DOWN: KeyCode: 50 '2', KeySym: 65505 '<E1>', String: ''
DOWN: KeyCode: 38 '&', KeySym: 65 'A', String: 'A'
DOWN: KeyCode: 37 '%', KeySym: 65507 '<E3>', String: ''
DOWN: KeyCode: 38 '&', KeySym: 97 'a', String: '^A'
DOWN: KeyCode: 64 '@', KeySym: 65513 '<E9>', String: ''
DOWN: KeyCode: 38 '&', KeySym: 97 'a', String: 'a'
```

It seems like the keysym is always the same as the string representation for printable characters. Is this guaranteed for all languages? If it is I could always take the keysym as key into the `key_states` map. Then the above use case would look like:

```
void onKeyDown(int keysym)
{
  key_states[keysym] = true;
}
void onKeyUp(int keysym)
{
  key_states[keysym] = false;
}
void update()
{
  // Check if Ctrl-a was pressed.
  if (key_states[Key::Ctrl] && key_states['a'])
  {
    // Do something.
  }
}
```

Would this work platform and language independently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an existing cross platform framework.  Search the internet for "C++ cross platform framework review" to "find the best one".

Comment: If it would be a more complicated problem I'd do. But it seems not that hard for this particular issue.

Comment: Going along with what @ThomasMatthews said, look into a framework. SDL2 (https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) is really lightweight, easy to use and handles all of this really well.